# How to use bash functions with fish

Tags: bash, fish

I have few bash functions like

```
#!/bin/sh

git-ci() {
    ...
}
```

When I was not using fish I had a `source ~/.my_functions` line in my `~/.bash_profile` but now it doesn't work.

Can I use my bash functions with fish? Or the only way is to translate them into fish ones and then save them via `funcsave xxx`?

Comment: /bin/sh is usaly not bash.

Comment: @Cyrus When you source a file, the shebang line is ignored

Comment: You have to translate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for defining functions in `fish` is very different from POSIX shell and `bash`.

The POSIX function:

```
hi () { 
    echo hello
}
```

is translated to:

```
function hi
    echo hello
end
```

There are other differences in scripting syntax. See the section titled **Blocks** in [Fish - The friendly interactive shell](https://lwn.net/Articles/136232/) for examples.

So it's basically not possible to try to use functions that were written for `bash` in `fish`, they're as different as `bash` and `csh`. You'll have to go through all your functions and convert them to `fish` syntax.

Comment: I know how syntax differs. This is sad.

Comment: Compatibility was not a goal of fish.

Comment: This doesn't make me happier but I think it wouldn't be very hard to rewrite my functions.

Comment: You have two choices: switch to `fish` and rewrite your functions, or stay with `bash`.

Comment: Lol. I understand what compatibility means :)

Comment: Though I never used pure bash, I used zsh.

Comment: zsh and bash are both POSIX-conforming, but fish isn't. Seems like a very poor decision of the designers.

Answer (score 4):

As @Barmer said fish doesn't care about compatibility because one of its goals is

> Sane Scripting
>
> fish is fully scriptable, and its syntax is simple, clean, and consistent. You'll never write esac again.

The fish folks think bash is insane and I personally agree.

One thing you can do is to have your bash functions in separate files and call them as functions from within fish.

Example:

Before

```
#!/bin/bash

git-ci() {
    ...
}

some_other_function() {
    ...
}
```

After

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: git-ci

# Content of git-ci function here
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# file: some_other_function

# Content of some_other_function function here
```

Then put your script files somewhere in your path. Now you can call them from fish.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change all the syntax, one workaround is to simply create a fish function that runs a bash script and passes the arguments right along.

**Example**

If you have a function like this

```sh
sayhi () { 
    echo Hello, $1!
}
```

you'd just change it by stripping away the function part, and save it as an executable script

```sh
echo Hello, $1!
```

and then create a fish function which calls that script (with the name `sayhi.fish`, for example)

```sh
function sayhi 
    # run bash script and pass on all arguments
    /bin/bash absolute/path/to/bash/script $argv
end
```

and, voila, just run it as you usually would

```
> sayhi ivkremer
Hello, ivkremer!
```